# How can I disable Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

How can I temporarily disable the asset pipeline functionality that Rails 3.1 provides?
(I am performing an upgrade)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this in your `application.rb`

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: but scaffold still generating assets

Comment: @eveevans add `--skip-assets`

Answer (score 5):

Putting this line inside the **application.rb**

`config.assets.enabled = false`

You can also disable the asset pipeline while creating a new application by passing the —skip-sprockets option.

`rails new appname --skip-sprockets`

You can use `--skip-assets` with `generate` to skip producing asset stubs.

refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: --skip-sprockets is broken now when creating a new application; see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7596